# List of characters who have been able to Withstand Lord Vishnu's chakra or Shiva's Trisula?

Tags: scripture, shiva, vishnu, weapon, sudarshana-chakra

Do the epics and Purānas mention any characters who have been able to resist and withstand the effects of Lord Vishnu's chakra or Lord Shiva's Trisula in a battle?

If possible, please provide a thorough list of the characters alongwith the scriptural references pertaining to them.

Comment: @estimator please write an answer citing the references. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Mandara, One of the sons of Hiranyakashipu became impervious to Vishnu's Sudarshana chakra due to Shiva's boon.

> He who took his birth as the Danava named Hiranyakashipu, whose
> strength was so great that he could shake the very mountains of Meru,
> succeeded in obtaining from Mahadeva the puissance belonging to all
> the deities and enjoyed it for ten millions of years. **He who was the
> foremost of all his sons and who was celebrated by the name of
> Mandara, succeeded, through the boon he had obtained from Mahadeva, in
> fighting Sakra for a million of years. The terrible discus of Vishnu
> and the thunderbolt of Indra were both unable to make the slightest
> impression, O Kesava, in days of yore, upon the body of that great
> cause of universal affliction.** The discus which thou bearest, O
> sinless one, was given unto thee by Mahadeva after he had slain a
> Daitya that was proud of his strength and used to live within the
> waters. That discus, blazing with energy and like unto fire, was
> created by the great god having for his device the bull. Wonderful and
> irresistible in energy it was given unto thee by that illustrious god.
> In consequence of its blazing energy it was incapable of being gazed
> at by any person save Siva the wielder of Pinaka. It was for this
> reason that Bhava (Siva) bestowed upon it the name of Sudarsana.
> **From that time the name Sudarsana came to be current in all the worlds. Even the weapon, O Kesava, failed to make the slightest
> impression on the body of Hiranyakashipu's son Mandara, that appeared
> like an evil planet in the three worlds. Hundreds of Chakras like
> thine and thunderbolts like that of Sakra, could not inflict a scratch
> on the body of that evil planet endued with great might, who had
> obtained a boon from Mahadeva**

**[The Mahabharata Book 13: Anusasana Parva - SECTION XIV](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a014.htm)**

Tarakasura withstood Vishnu's chakra due to Brahma's boon as per **Matsya Purana 153.199-201**. In the below anecdote, Vishnu hurls his chakra at the demon's chest , but it simply shatters due to the effects of the boon.

[image]